# Unable to create channel after adding org3 to first-network sample

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have updated to hyperledger fabric 1.4.0 and tried to recreate first-network sample with three Orgs. I am able to spin up a network with a solo orderer container, 3 ca containers, 6 peer containers with one couchdb container for each and a cli container.

After starting the network, when i try to create channel using this command,

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c threeorgschannel -f ./ch
annel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I get an error saying,

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

My files is at [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/asadhayat1068/manual3orgsnetwork).

Debug level orderer and peer logs are as follow
**PEER LOGS (CLI CONTAINER)**

```
root@571d8370d79d:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c threeorgschannel -f ./ch
annel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem 
2019-01-14 16:28:48.872 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 001 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP
2019-01-14 16:28:48.872 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 002 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2019-01-14 16:28:48.872 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 003 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.Default setting to string SW
2019-01-14 16:28:48.872 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 004 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW
2019-01-14 16:28:48.873 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 005 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore
2019-01-14 16:28:48.873 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 006 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: unexpected end of JSON input
2019-01-14 16:28:48.873 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 007 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to string 
2019-01-14 16:28:48.873 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 008 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2019-01-14 16:28:48.873 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 009 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Hash setting to string SHA2
2019-01-14 16:28:48.873 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00a Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: 256
2019-01-14 16:28:48.873 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00b Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Security setting to int 256
2019-01-14 16:28:48.874 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00c Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11
2019-01-14 16:28:48.874 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00d Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.874 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00e Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Library setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.874 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00f Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.875 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 010 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Label setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.875 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 011 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.875 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 012 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Pin setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.875 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 013 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.875 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 014 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Hash setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.876 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 015 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.876 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 016 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Security setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.876 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 017 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore
2019-01-14 16:28:48.876 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 018 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 019 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [viperutil] EnhancedExactUnmarshalKey -> DEBU 01a map[peer.BCCSP:map[SW:map[FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:] Hash:SHA2 Security:256] PKCS11:map[Library:<nil> Label:<nil> Pin:<nil> Hash:<nil> Security:<nil> FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:<nil>]] Default:SW]]
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> DEBU 01b KeyStore opened at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore]...done
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [bccsp] initBCCSP -> DEBU 01c Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01d Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01e Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01f Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-01-14 16:28:48.877 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 021 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/admincerts
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 022 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/admincerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 023 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 024 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 025 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 026 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 027 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 028 TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 029 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02a crls folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02b MSP configuration file not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml]: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml: no such file or directory]
2019-01-14 16:28:48.878 UTC [msp] newBccspMsp -> DEBU 02c Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2019-01-14 16:28:48.879 UTC [msp] New -> DEBU 02d Creating Cache-MSP instance
2019-01-14 16:28:48.879 UTC [msp] loadLocaMSP -> DEBU 02e Created new local MSP
2019-01-14 16:28:48.879 UTC [msp] Setup -> DEBU 02f Setting up MSP instance Org1MSP
2019-01-14 16:28:48.879 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 030 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-01-14 16:28:48.879 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 031 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-01-14 16:28:48.898 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 032 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-01-14 16:28:48.898 UTC [bccsp_sw] loadPrivateKey -> DEBU 033 Loading private key [8af400b7a17b4fbf91a88542a54b1465956864e413620ca2e7b196edbbe7a4be] at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/8af400b7a17b4fbf91a88542a54b1465956864e413620ca2e7b196edbbe7a4be_sk]...
2019-01-14 16:28:48.899 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 034 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-01-14 16:28:48.899 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 035 Signing identity expires at 2029-01-11 13:28:00 +0000 UTC
2019-01-14 16:28:48.899 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2019-01-14 16:28:48.900 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 037 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-14 16:28:48.900 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 parsed scheme: ""
2019-01-14 16:28:48.900 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 039 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-01-14 16:28:48.901 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03a ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2019-01-14 16:28:48.901 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-01-14 16:28:48.901 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002bae70, CONNECTING
2019-01-14 16:28:49.991 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 03d grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host". Reconnecting...
2019-01-14 16:28:49.991 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03e pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002bae70, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2019-01-14 16:28:49.992 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002bae70, CONNECTING
2019-01-14 16:28:49.995 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 040 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host". Reconnecting...
2019-01-14 16:28:49.995 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 041 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002bae70, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2019-01-14 16:28:51.477 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 042 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002bae70, CONNECTING
2019-01-14 16:28:51.482 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 043 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host". Reconnecting...
2019-01-14 16:28:51.482 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 044 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0002bae70, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
root@571d8370d79d:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#
```

** ORDERER LOGS **

```
2019-01-14 16:25:03.538 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 003 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2019-01-14 16:25:03.545 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 004 Getting block information from block storage
2019-01-14 16:25:04.047 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newLedgerResources -> PANI 005 Error creating channelconfig bundle: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.example.com")
panic: Error creating channelconfig bundle: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.example.com")

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000ec840, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x515
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc00015e268, 0x4, 0xf6f983, 0x27, 0xc000563808, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc00015e268, 0xf6f983, 0x27, 0xc000563808, 0x1, 0x1)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc00015e270, 0xf6f983, 0x27, 0xc000563808, 0x1, 0x1)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.(*Registrar).newLedgerResources(0xc00022e5a0, 0xc000281400, 0xc000281400)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:260 +0x2d7
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.(*Registrar).Initialize(0xc00022e5a0, 0xc000505560)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:147 +0x242
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.initializeMultichannelRegistrar(0xc0000b6cc0, 0xc0003081d0, 0x0, 0xc00022e3f0, 0x19b4420, 0xc000308390, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc0003083a0, 0x2, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:414 +0x2ec
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Start(0xf4dfc0, 0x5, 0xc0004b6c00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:142 +0x52d
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:87 +0x1ce
main.main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```